# Why google charts are without right click menu?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Is there a reason why there isn't a default browser context menu on google charts? And am I missing an option that could allow one?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: Which example with context menu are you referring to? Can you post some of the code you are currently implementing?

Comment: I simply want to have the default context menu from the browser shown. E.g. every chart on the [main page](https://developers.google.com/chart/) is without one.

Comment: That makes more sense, I edited your question

Answer (score 1):

The link that you have posted is of google's chart page i.e. https://developers.google.com/chart/

On this page the chart is rendered as SVG inside a `div` with the `id="chart_div"` which acts as chart area wrapper / container. Inside this div there are two more nested `div`s. The last nested `div` has its `contextmenu` event disabled thru javascript.

In order to test this, open the source in developer tools and add `oncontextmenu="alert('hello');"` to this div and then check try right-click.

Now for your question: Why? This is perhaps because Google Charts are interactive charts and lot of informational popups are dependent on `hover` and `click`. They must have thought to keep the chart area clean without any distracting context menus on it. Context menu might not have any useful purpose on the chart itself. However, this is only my speculation.